# Multiple chained planning variable leads to same Anchor

Tags: drools, optaplanner, kie, drools-planner

In Optaplanner, is there a way to assign multiple chains that leads to same Anchor? Is this a feature provided by optaplanner?

For eg. (Task planning with Vehicle Routing app) I have an employee emp who does 20 tasks in a day. For first 10 tasks, as those are distant tasks from his office, he used a Car. Then planner planned him to reach back at office and take bike for next 10 tasks, which are nearer to his office.

I need help with 2 problems:
A. How does planner plan employee emp to reach back to office ending a task-chain (for first 10 tasks)?
B. How does planner make a new chain that leads to same Anchor(emp) (for next 10 tasks)?

If current version of Optaplanner does not support this then what are the suggestions you could provide to accommodate such feature?

Answer (score 2):

no, **PlanningVariableGraphType.TREE (directed graph) doesn't exist yet** in 7.3. It will be an alternative to PlanningVariableGraphType.CHAINED.

See `PlanningVariableGraphType.java`

Comment: any idea when will it be available? Will it also have cyclic graphs in future?

Comment: 1) no
2) that's yet another type